# I can'nt install zend studio 7.2.1

Tags: zend

i can'nt install zend studio 7.2.1
the error is like this

Preparing to install...
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...
strings: '/lib/libc.so.6': No such file

Launching installer...

ZendStudio7_2_1.bin: 2479: exec: /tmp/install.dir.4666/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: not found

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the libc6 package
To install it
Type this in terminal `sudo apt-get install libc6`